# Do we want to merge answers from this cross-post onto our site?

Tags: discussion, migration

A user posted a question here, [How should I deal with a client who refuses to pay after receiving the finish product?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-should-i-deal-with-a-client-who-refuses-to-pay-after-receiving-the-finish-pr), and also cross-posted the same exact post on [The Workplace SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27773/is-it-unethical-to-sabotage-client-website-who-refused-to-pay).

The post on Workplace SE was closed; however, it seems like it is getting good answers. I considered having the duplicate on Workplace SE migrated here and the answers merged with our version of the post.

However, the Workplace SE posts has a top answer score of +15, which would eclipse the top scored version on our site. *Cross-posting is generally frowned upon precisely for this very reason: It spreads information out across different places and makes it harder to merge it all back together without causing issues.*

So my question is, do we want to include those answers on our site, or do we just simply leave the comment linking the two posts together?  Take a look at the two posts, and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say to leave it be. Linking is enough, and the workplace one is already closed.

Questions shouldn't be cross-site posted, as we all know. This user may not have known, but it was already closed on Workplace, so I didn't do any mod actions here. The question is OK, and able to get answers - Some good answers from the Workplace though. If we move it over, those users will lose reputation on their site (and that's 5 users, if I recall correctly?), and gain phantom reputation here. Do any of them have an account here?

At least here, more people can post answers to, helping everyone.

Comment: Thanks Luke. What's your thought process behind this idea?

Comment: @jmort253 Updated

Comment: Okay, thats what I was thinking too. Thanks again.